# Setup Exe File created with InstallShield does not install the Outlook Add In successfully

Tags: c#, outlook, windows-installer, installshield, outlook-addin

I have created an installer project using Install Shield on Visual Studio which is required to install a custom VSTO add in to Outlook. The setup file is created as required and it runs without any issues, all of the files that are required are installed to the correct directory and all the registry files are added to the users registry as required.

However, Outlook does not seem to be finding the add in at all. Can anyone point me in the right direction with this?

Comment: You should say something about whether the version of Office is 32 or 64-bit and what your setup is, 32 or 64 in case it's just a mismatch in the registry etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For anyone in the UK - The registry entry "LoadBehavior" must be spelled exactly as it appears here.** I used the UK spelling "LoadBehaviour" and it was the sole reason my install was not successful. I was held back for several days due to this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that you did all the steps described in the [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx) article.

Do you see the add-in listed in the COM add-ins list in Outlook?

Make sure the right windows registry hive is used. Note, it depends on the Outlook/Windows bitness.

Comment: This is the same guide that I followed step by step, I will look at the registry keys again to see if they should be placed somewhere else, but the click once application that was used to do this previously placed the registry keys in the same place.

The add in is not appearing in the COM add-ins list.